# Combine md5 sums of parts to get md5 sum of full string

Tags: encryption, md5, sha1

Is it possible to combine two md5 sums of a sentence to get the md5 sum of the final sentence? e.g. i have the sentence "I dont like working", and now i want to do

> md5("I dont ") + md5("like working") = md5("I dont like working")

Also, is this possible with SHA1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The point of a hash algorithm is that it will produce different results for similar inputs. If it were true that the sum of hashes could produce the hash of the final, it would be trivial to recover the value of a hashed string by figuring out the hashes of each letter and working the sum backwards.

A good hashing algorithm produces very different results for any (small or large) change in the input, and produces changes which are impossible to relate to the change.

SHA1 is better than MD5 in this respect. MD5 isn't really considered secure anymore.

Comment: thanks for your answers. to refine my question i want to do the following: i have the md5hash of "I dont " but not the string. i have however the string "like work". is it possible to generate the final hash of "I dont like work" using only the md5sum of the first part and the string "like work"? im not sure if adam already answered this. its like the code of the first answer only that i start at line 5, and set the current digest to the md5sum of the first part.

Comment: so the md5 hashing algorithm has more in its memory than just the current hash when digesting a stream? in order to resume the digest at a later time i would need to save all memory tables and not just the md5 hash correct?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 When hashing a stream, the next block is int'd with the results of the last block. When done, the last values left in the state machine are the hash. I'd say wait until you have all the data, then hash.

Comment: thanks, from what i see in the wiki entry it should be possible to get the h0,h1,h2,h3 state values from the hash. i will try it out myself. thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in python, but behind the scenes it's just concatenating all of the strings for you.

```
import md5

m = md5.new()
m.update("I dont ")
m.update("like working")
print m.hexdigest()  # b436bd6442ee000b4778bdbc8bee71d9

m = md5.new()
m.update("I dont like working")
print m.hexdigest()  # b436bd6442ee000b4778bdbc8bee71d9
```

Comment: is it not taking advantage of the blocks ? you could push new string parts until a block is full, then it would just discard all the string content that served to calculate this one block, because its been digested. that would put a limit to the max memory used. imagine updating a few gigabytes of string content from streaming of disk data.